# AMPScript IF ELSE statement returns 'FALSE' unexpectedly

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have the following AMPScript:

```
%%[
var @Custom_2, @variable

set @Custom_2 = Custom_2

if Not Empty(@Custom_2) then
     set @variable = concat(" ",@Custom_2)
elseif Empty(@Custom_2) then
    set @variable = ""
endif
]%%
```

And am printing the results in an email with:

```
%%=v(@variable)=%%
```

Custom_2 is a nullable text field. When previewing a record with an empty Custom_2, the word 'FALSE' is printed when the expected value is nothing should be printed.

Using this AMPscript below resolves the issue, as does renaming the Custom_2 field to anything else, but I don't understand why.

```
 if Not Empty(@Custom_2) AND Not(@Custom_2 == "False") then 
   set @variable = concat(" ",@Custom_2)
 endif
```

Both Custom_1 and Custom_2 share the same field properties. I've tried deleting the field from the data extension then re-adding it, only to encounter the same issue.

Is there documentation that explains why this would be occurring?

Comment: Please update your question to include the code that's setting the `@Custom_2` variable -- prior to your conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you by chance have a Profile Attribute named `Custom_2`?  That could be the source of the `False` value.  Profile Attribute values will take precedent over data extension field values.

In general, I would not recommend referencing send context variables without checking to see if they exist or not -- using [**AttribueValue()**](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue).

I'd add some debugging output before and after your conditional.

I'd also simplify your conditional.  Doesn't appear that the `elseif` is needed -- or the any `else` for that matter.

```ampscript
%%[
var @Custom_2, @variable

set @debug = 1
set @Custom_2 = AttributeValue("Custom_2")

if @debug == 1 then
  output(concat("<br>custom_2: |", @custom_2,"|"))
endif

set @variable = ""

if Not Empty(@Custom_2) then
     set @variable = concat(" ",@Custom_2)
endif

if @debug == 1 then
  output(concat("<br>variable: |", @variable,"|"))
endif

]%%
```